# Displaying data in sections in a Table View using Core Data in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have some troubles with displaying data grouped in sections in a table view using Core Data in Swift.

I will illustrate the problem using an example. Lets assume three classes: Order, Product and Service. Class Order has an attribute "date" and to-many relationships with Product and with Service.

For each order, a section should be created to display all products and services ordered at a specific date.

With NSFetchedResultsController all orders are fetched based on the atttribute date. This provides the correct number of sections. 
However, I encounter problems to display all products and services in seperate rows per section since "numberOfRowsInSection" is based on the number of orders and not on the number of products and services.

Below is the code to illustrate my problem. Hopefully, anybody could help me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance,

Gerard

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ExampleViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

var orders = [Order]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchedResultController.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self

    fetchData()
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return fetchedResultController.sections?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let sectionInfo = fetchedResultController.sections![section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    // Unfortunatelly, this provides not the total number of products and services per section
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let textCellIdentifier = "ExampleTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExampleTableViewCell

    let order = orders[indexPath.row] // Data fetched using NSFetchedResultsController

    let products = order.products!.allObjects as! [Product] // Swift Array
    let services = order.services!.allObjects as! [Service] // Swift Array

    // Each product and each service should be displayed in separate rows. 
    // Instead, all products and services are displayed in a single row as below
    var displaytext = ""
    for product in products {
        displaytext += product.name! + "\n"
    }

    for service in services {
        displaytext += service.name! + "\n"
    }

    cell.orderLabel.text = displaytext // display text in ExampleTableViewCell

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if let sections = fetchedResultController.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        return currentSection.name
    }
    return nil
}


func orderFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Order")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ AND date <= %@", startDate, endDate) // startDate and endData are defined elsewhere

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    return fetchRequest
}

func fetchData() {
    let fetchRequest = orderFetchRequest()
    fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "date", cacheName: nil)

    do {
        orders = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Order]
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    do {
        try fetchedResultController.performFetch()
    }
    catch _ {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: so you want one section for each order, and in each section rows for all of the products and then rows for all of the services? FRC isn't going to help you easily with that. It wants to show orders and drill down to products and services...

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. In fact, I hoped that is was possible to fetch the data of parent class Order (with NSSortDescriptor and NSPredicate), and to provide Table View the number of rows for each section based on the number of instances of child classes Product and Service. When this is not (easily) possible with NSFetchedResultsController, would there be another way to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wain has said, the FRC doesn't help much.  An FRC has two main advantages, over and above an ordinary fetch: it can manage the sections for you, and it can automatically handle inserts/deletes/updates, via its delegate methods.  The first is of no use in your case, since you want one section per Order.  And the second is of little help since the FRC will watch only one Entity for changes, yet your table view is built from three.

Nevertheless, I think you might be able to use an FRC to some effect.  First, do not bother with `sectionNameKeyPath`: you have a one-one mapping between `Orders` and table view sections, so you can use the tableview's `section` as an index on the FRC's `fetchedObjects` to identify the order for each section.  The `numberOrRowsInSection` can then be found by summing the count of `products` and `services` for the relevant `Order`.  The messy (and possibly slow) bit is mapping the table view's row to the correct element of either `products` or `services`.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ExampleViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
    var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

    var orders = [Order]()
    var startDate : NSDate = NSDate()
    var endDate : NSDate = NSDate()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchedResultController.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        fetchData()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects!.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let order = fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects![section] as! Order
        return ((order.products?.count ?? 0) + (order.services?.count ?? 0))
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let textCellIdentifier = "ExampleTableViewCell"
        let row = indexPath.row

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExampleTableViewCell

        let order = fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects![indexPath.section] as! Order // Data fetched using NSFetchedResultsController
        let products = (order.products?.allObjects ?? [Product]()) as! [Product] // Swift Array
        let services = (order.services?.allObjects ?? [Service]()) as! [Service] // Swift Array

        if (row < products.count) { // this is a Product row
            cell.orderLabel.text = products[row].name!
        } else { // this is a Service row
            cell.orderLabel.text = services[row-products.count].name!
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let order = fetchedResultController.fetchedObjects![section] as! Order
        return "\(order.date)"
    }


    func orderFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Order")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ AND date <= %@", startDate, endDate) // startDate and endData are defined elsewhere

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        return fetchRequest
    }

    func fetchData() {
        let fetchRequest = orderFetchRequest()
        fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath:nil, cacheName: nil)

        do {
            try fetchedResultController.performFetch()
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

There are probably neater ways to code this; I'm not a Swift aficionado.

If you use the FRC delegate methods, you can at least watch for new/deleted Orders and add/delete sections to the TV as necessary, and you could use updates to reload the relevant section.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It is a pity that only one entity can be watched for changes using FRC, but the work-around you proposed works exactly as I wanted!